# How to load data from a CSV file to MySQL table using java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

We need to load data from a CSV file, which our client has provided, into a MySQL table. We are using the below code.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/chan/Desktop/gradeschool-student-sorting-app/Output/conertedCSV.csv' INTO TABLE student_temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

While loading manually, it is working fine. But while executing the above through java it is throwing some exceptions.

> ```
> Query: LOAD DATA INFILE C:/Users/chan/Desktop/gradeschool-student-sorting-app/Output/conertedCSV.csv
> INTO TABLE student_temp
>     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
>     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
>     LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
>     IGNORE 1 LINES;
> Connection successful
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:/Users/s521753/Desktop/gradeschool-student-sorting-app/Output/conertedCSV.csv' at line 1
> Executed query successfully
> ```

Comment: show your code, most likely you are not escaping your query string properly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Just now i found the issue in my code. I am getting error just because of the file location mismatch. As the error is not displaying as file not found, i took this much time to resolve this. Thanks again.